# Validation on an Attribute Comparing another Attribute of another Iterator

Tags: jdeveloper, oracle-adf

JDev 11.1.1.5.0
I have two tables in the form, one read only A and one editable B.
There is an attribute called terms in the table B and an attribute called limit in table A.
I want to validate the key-in of terms in table B for which it should not be greater than the value of limit in table A.

Answer (score 0):

You can create custom validation on EntityObjectImpl of table B
do below steps in your code
1-Create object of EntityObjectImpl of table A
2-Get value of attribute limit in table A
3-Compare the value of two attribute and handle your validation